# How can I activate an area of redstone all at once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

The idea behind my contraption is to trap players in lava by deactivating an area of fence gates under some carpet. This pushes the players upwards into the lava and there items fall onto the carpet. (Basically killing a player with lava without burning their items.)

My problem is that I'm not sure how to toggle the full area of fence gates from the underneath.

(Where the grass is below the fence gates.)
[image: Image for context:]

The solutions I thought of are:

1. I can try and toggle a bunch of redstone torches underneath (due to them activating upwards), but then how do I activate the torches?
2. Observers also activate upwards, but for only a tick, how can I make it on/off like the torches?

If you have any ideas on how to fix my issue, please share them here. If you have any redesigns for a more improvised trap, please put them here as well. (No commands/No mods) Thank you!

Comment: Where does the player start, on top or below? I don't understand what should push the player anywhere.

Comment: The Players walk on the carpet when the fence gates underneath are open. When the fencegates close, it pushes the player up.

Comment: Ah yes, the very subtle trap of convincing the player to walk 0.01nm below lava. :D
How about just having a few random ones closed and the rest open, no redstone at all? The player can't see where the closed one is and will step up automatically, just by walking around. By having a solid ceiling instead of lava, you can make an invisible maze out of this.

Comment: It's not supposed to be subtle,  I want it to lead somewhere and be able to toggle access on and off.

Comment: Then you can just flip a line. Redstone line into row of repeaters into row of blocks with row of redstone torches on top, below the fence gates. The only ways I currently know to toggle an entire layer of fence gates are some super complicated setup that grows more and more the further down it goes, which is a huge contraption, or using a bunch of slime blocks and honey blocks with redstone blocks attached to them, activated by rows of pistons, or abusing a bug to let sticky pistons drop their attached blocks and something with observers and a flying machine below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I wrote my last comment, I had an idea that's at least not overly terrible. It works with arbitrarily large planes, is "just" 6 blocks tall and at most 3 blocks longer in one direction and 1 in another than the area you want to toggle. That's already way better than anything else I could think of.

[image: sticky blocks pushing up redstone blocks]

The idea was to use slime/honey blocks to increase the amount of redstone blocks you can move towards the fence gates at once, basically shrinking the problem of how many blocks need to be powered at once. Theoretically you could use 6 slime/honey blocks and 6 redstone blocks each, but due to the eternally annoying bug [MC-108](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-108), this doesn't work. The redstone blocks need to be even further away from the pistons, so you can only use 5 redstone blocks per piston.

You could use a similar method to power up to 11 pistons at a time with redstone blocks, but then the circuit would grow even further downwards.
You can make the rows of redstone and repeaters longer between the parts where the signal snakes around, to use the full power level 15, and you can infinitely tile this pattern, alternating between slime and honey blocks wherever they touch.
There's probably a way to make the redstone/repeater part a bit more compact, but it's probably usually not worth it.

This all looks really messy, but it might be the easiest way. A similar problem are 1×1 lamp screens where every pixel can be controlled individually, which experts have worked on for years. Those contraptions can get extremely complicated.
In general, whenever you can avoid this problem, do that instead.